# Regex for password requirements, no trailing whitespace

Tags: regex, passwords, whitespace, trailing

I was unable to find correct regex for my case. I found almost perfect, but it still passes with leading spaces.

Requirements:

```
var regex = /^\s*(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[a-zA-Z])([a-zA-Z0-9]+)\s*$/;

var passwd = "abcdefg12345" //Passes
var passwd = " abcdefg12345" //Does not pass
var passwd = "abcdefg 12345" //Does not pass
var passwd = "abcdefg12345 " //Passes but should not
```

Any advise?

Also I would like to add minimum requirement for length, how should that be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to prevent leading or trailing spaces, just remove the last `\s`. To set a minimum length for the password, change your `+` quantifier to `{n,}`, where *n* is the minimum length.

For example, the following pattern matches any sequence of 5 or more alphanumeric characters that contains at least one letter, and at least one number:

```
/^(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[a-zA-Z])([a-zA-Z0-9]{5,})$/
```

Comment: Cheers. There seems to be problem with AngularJS and variable whitespaces. It trims all whitespaces out of strings so it is impossible to validate string with trailing whitespace :D Im looking for solution for this.

Comment: @AngularAddict I see. Well, unfortunately I know very little about AngularJS, so that might warrant another question.